# TFS Query History with Physical File Path Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a piece of code that queries the history of tfs but on my machine I get an exception
saying:

> There is no working folder mapping for C:\SDAM.

However if I run this same piece of code in colleagues machine there is no problem.

I am using:

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; version 10
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client; version 10
- VS2012 Project Update 4
- 4.5 Framework

Things I have tried:

1. Refreshing the cache
2. Delete the cache.
3. Checked the working folders and added them using Team Foundation Sidekicks to be sure I have source control folder and local folder mapped.
4. I have passed in the source control folder path $/SDAM and I get history. I go into to tfs explorer and check that $/SDAM is mapped to C:\SDAM

I am completely baffled and any suggestions would be appreciated. This code is already being used widely by us and I need to reuse it.

The results of

```
tf workspaces /format:detailed /collection:http://XXXX/tfs/
```

> Workspace  : XXXXXXXX
>   Owner      : Domain\zzzzzzz
>   Computer   : XXXXXXXX
>   Comment    :
>   Collection : cccc\ddddd
>   Permissions: Private
>   Location   : Server
>   File Time  : Current
>
> Working folders:
>   $/SDAM: C:\SDAM

---

```
IEnumerable tfsHistory;

string SourceControlPath = @"C:\SDAM";

var tfsUri = new Uri(@"http://XXXX/tfs/");
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

VersionSpec fromVersion = null, toVersion = null;
fromVersion = new ChangesetVersionSpec(1);
toVersion = new ChangesetVersionSpec(2);
tfsHistory = 
    vcs.QueryHistory(
        SourceControlPath, 
        LatestVersionSpec.Instance, 
        0, 
        RecursionType.Full, 
        null, 
        fromVersion, 
        toVersion, 
        Int32.MaxValue, 
        true, 
        false);

if (tfsHistory != null)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to query against the locally mapped path, and can't just use the server path of `$/SDAM/`?

Comment: Yes as at the time I only know the locally mapped path.

Comment: Does changing the value of the username parameter help?

Comment: No its same exception being returned.

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the anonymised results of `tf workspaces /format:detailed /collection:http://XXXX/tfs/` into the question?

Comment: Added in results anonymised results of tf workspaces /format:detailed /collection:http://XXXX/tfs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tool cannot find a working folder mapping because it is not in the working folder cache for the version of the SDK you're building against.  If you do not specify a Team Project Collection and want to get connected to TFS by only a local path, TFS will look in the working folder cache to determine what server and server path correspond to that local path.

If you're building against version 10.0 of the SDK, then it's looking for the working folder cache created by Visual Studio 10.0 (ie, Visual Studio 2010.)

However, if you're running Visual Studio 11.0 and `tf` 11.0, then it will store the working folder information in the working folder cache for Visual Studio 11.0 (ie, Visual Studio 2012.)

Thus, your tool cannot bootstrap itself with only a working folder mapping.  You need to either:

1. Have your tool connect to the TFS server in question so that it will obtain a fresh copy of the working folder information
2. Match the version of the SDK you build against to the version of TFS you use with Visual Studio

If you want to dynamically load the newest SDK, you may be able to [bind an assembly resolution handler](http://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/application-compatibility-with-tfs-2005-and-tfs-2008).

Comment: Thank you very much, you nailed it. It was a new machine and I had just run VS2012 only and not vs2010. Once I set the workspaces in 2010 all was right in the world. All makes sense now but not at the time.